# Adding dynamic label values to an alert message. (Once per bar.)

Tags: algorithm, pine-script, tostring, trading

I have created an indicator that analysis every price candle with over 100 algorithms and alerts me with a buy or sell signal if at least 30 of 100> calculations met for that candle. (last candle)
the problem here is i can only get an alert signal with a simple text: sell signal or buy signal.
I need to include signal strength (number of signals) within my alert messages. I've already managed to label the current signal numbers above or below the candles but i can't include them within alert messages. I'm not sure what is missing here.
I need more definitive alert messages such as;

Sell Signal.
Signal Strength: 68

Buy Signal
Signal Strength: 71

Etc.

here are the values that i use to draw the labels.

```
 if showsignum and signum_top > 0
        signum_text_top := signum_text_top + tostring(signum_top)
 if showsignum and signum_bottom > 0
        signum_text_bottom := signum_text_bottom + tostring(signum_bottom)
 if signum_text_top != ""
        if showlast
            delete_old_neg_sig_labels()
        array.push(neg_sig_labels, 
                      label.new( x = bar_index, 
                                 y = max(high, high[1]), 
                                 text = signum_text_top,
                                 color = red,
                                 textcolor = black,
                                 style = label.style_label_down
                                 ))
if signum_text_bottom != ""
        if showlast
            delete_old_pos_sig_labels()
        array.push(pos_sig_labels, 
                      label.new( x = bar_index, 
                                 y = min(low, low[1]), 
                                 text = signum_text_bottom,
                                 color = green, 
                                 textcolor = black,
                                 style = label.style_label_up
                                 ))
```

[image: how it works:]

alertconditon that I use to receive sell or buy alerts.

```
alertcondition(pos_sig_detected, title='Positive Signal Detection', message='Buy Signal')
alertcondition(ned_sig_detected, title='NEgative Signal Detection', message='Sell Signal')
```

I tried many other alternatives such as adding tostring value to the alert message without any luck.
I need to push the number of signals written on the labels (signum_text_bottom or signum_text_top) with my alert messages.

Regards,

Comment: Is this a strategy or an indicator? Are you able to plot those two variables?

Comment: :( So i tried plotting tostring(signum_bottom) as "Signal Strength" and added to alert message with {{plot("Signal Strength")}} and it worked! :))
Thanks a lot.

Comment: But this causes error "Memory limits exceeded" even if i set max_bars_back to 10.

I simply used plotchar as:

```
plotchar(dnumdiv_top, "Signal Strength")
```